# Handlebars in action form method

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to display different pages with the POST method using handlebars and #each loop. The buttons are displayed correctly, with texts according to the loop. However, on click they send me on the same exact page (first one in my loop). Does this mean that the loop doesn't work in the action method? What is a better way to do it?

home.handlebars file

```
<div id="myDiv">  
    {{#each classes}}
     <form class="formClasses" action="/subject/{{this}}" role="form" method="POST">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">{{this}}</button>
    {{/each}}   
</div>
```

index.js file

```
app.post('/subject/:this', function(req, res){
    res.render('subject');
});
```

Comment: They are sending you to the same exact page because in your `index.js` the post route renders the same page `res.render('subject');`

Comment: So I should render different page for each case?

Comment: You could render the same page but inject the data to be consumed by the handlebars templates e.g. in your router `var data = {
    name: req.params.this }; res.render('subject', data);` And in your `subject.hbs` template display the data as `<p>
 The template still has a <em>name</em> property, which is <b>{{name}}</b> </p>`

Comment: The problem is that no matter what button do I click, the url stays the same (first `/subject/{{this}}` of my loop)